# How to assign Middleware to Routes in Laravel (better way)?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, frameworks, middleware

I would like to here your opinion or maybe your best known practice in assigning Middleware to Routes in Laravel. I have read 3 ways:

- Array (Single and Multiple)

  `Route::get('/',['middlware' => 'auth', function () {
       // Code goes here
  }]);`

  `Route::get('/', ['middleware' => ['first', 'second'], function () {
      //
  }]);`
- Chain Method

  `Route::get('/', function () {
          //
  })->middleware(['first', 'second']);`
- Fully Qualified Class Name

  `use App\Http\Middleware\FooMiddleware;
  Route::get('admin/profile', ['middleware' => FooMiddleware::class, function () {
      //
  }]);`

I just wanna know what is the best practices you know and if possible add some reference so that it is easier for us newbie to understand. Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Great question, but one which I'm afraid isn't suitable for StackoOverflow. Maybe you'll have bother luck at e.g. the Laracasts forums or laravel.io?

Comment: As I am searching for similar question, if there is a possibility of duplication. I haven't see one. 
Appreciated your comment. Joel

Comment: I will try to find it in the said forums.

Comment: Either of the first two methods (array or chained).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From my point of view, I prefer the **chain method** to assign middleware to any route as it looks so clean and easier. i.e,

```
Route::get('/', function () {
        //
})->middleware(['first', 'second']);
```

Comment: Does it execute in order? First, then second?

Answer (score 7):

From my point of view all versions are ok and I can't think of any advantages from one over the other. I like to group them like this.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('/home', [
        'as' => 'home',
        'uses' => 'Dashboard\DashboardController@dashboard'
    ]);  

    Route::pattern('users', '\d+');
    Route::resource('users','UserController'); 

   // more route definitions

});
```

Comment: Best one is `Route::middleware(['first', 'second'])->get('/index','App\Http\Controllers\ControllerPage@index');` (Works in Laravel 8) BUT YOU NEED TO SET THE CLOSURE LIKE [THIS](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#defining-middleware)