# Calling a laravel route from a different Domain

Tags: php, laravel, routes, cors

Let's say I have a next js application which exists in a different domain  that needs to call a laravel route. This route leads to a login page.

This is what I did on react side

```
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const result = await axios.get("http://localhost:5001/login", {
        headers: {
          // "content-type": "application/json",
            "x-api-signature": "my-secret-token",
        },
      });
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

I am getting cors error on front end

// In Laravel auth.php

```
        Route::get('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
                    ->name('login');
```

This route leads to a simple login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CORS Middleware for Laravel](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors)

---

Or by using middleware, something like (*not tested*)

Note that `https://stackoverflow.com` should be your app domain.

```
class Cors
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://stackoverflow.com')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization');
    }
}
```

---

Read

1. [Laravel CORS Guide: What It Is and How to Enable It](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/laravel-cors/)

Comment: tthanks, class Cors is the middleware for the route is it ?

Comment: @desh yes call it in routes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039159/how-to-assign-middleware-to-routes-in-laravel-better-way